# Should Lightsail DNS configuration match settings in Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Should AWS Lightsail's DNS Zone contain the same DNS records as my Route 53 configuration including NS, A and MX?

I am confused because this feel redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed redundant.

You shouldn't need Lightsail DNS configured at all unless you are *not* using Route 53.  Except in limited, advanced configurarion scenarios, the records in one or the other will just be ignored.

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't have to do anything at all in Lightsails' DNS Zone? Where do I set MX records for my Gmail then? Or does this fall in to one of advanced configuration scenarios? Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have a hosted zone in Route 53?  If so, put them there.  If not, please advise.

Comment: Yes I created a hosted zone in Route 53. What you are saying is I don't need this hosted zone in Route 53, correct? I can simply define extra MX records within Lightsail DNS zone?

Comment: Yes, you should only need one or the other.  Lightsail DNS supports a [limited subset](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/understanding-dns-in-amazon-lightsail) of what Route 53 does, but if you already have Lightsail DNS working for your domain, you should be able to do all of this in Lightsail DNS.